# cypress write customised logs into file with writeFile is a good idea?

Tags: cypress

I would like to write some customised logs into files with `cypress`. Such as 'current test case name', 'user's id used for this test', 'fail or pass', etc.

I googled awhile, found `cy.writeFile` meet my needs. But it seems most people would recommend `cy.task` for logging.

So is `cy.writeFile` for logging a good idea? If not, what's the reason?

Thanks!

BTW, here's the codes, very simple:

```
function logger (log) {
  cy.writeFile('logs/combined.log', log + '\n', { flag: 'a+' })
}

module.exports = {
  logger
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cy.task() command is used generally when you do not want the tests themselves to interrupt the logging or if you want to interact with the node process itself.  Whereas the cy.writeFile() has to be called between each test and cannot interact with the node process.   You can add things in your plugin files so that continous logs can be produced regardless of the test being ran and concatenate those things into the same file.

```
// in plugins/index.js file
on('task', {
  readJson: (filename) => {
    // reads the file relative to current working directory
    return fsExtra.readJson(path.join(process.cwd(), filename)
  }
})
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Command

> cy.task() provides an escape hatch for running arbitrary Node code, so
>   you can take actions necessary for your tests outside of the scope of
>   Cypress. This is great for:
>
> Seeding your test database. Storing state in Node that you want
>   persisted between spec files. Performing parallel tasks, like making
>   multiple http requests outside of Cypress. Running an external
>   process. In the task plugin event, the command will fail if undefined
>   is returned. This helps catch typos or cases where the task event is
>   not handled.
>
> If you do not need to return a value, explicitly return null to signal
>   that the given event has been handled.